# Output ruby array via an erb template

Tags: ruby, templates, erb, puppet

I'm using puppet to provide a set of constants for a ruby program.
I need to provide an array of hostnames over which my program will iterate.

In the bash script I was using before this, I simply had as a puppet variable

```
hosts => "host1,host2"
```

which I provided to the bash script as

```
HOSTS=<%= hosts %>
```

obviously this won't quite work for ruby - I need it in the format

```
hosts = ["host1","host2"]
```

since

```
p hosts
```

and

```
puts my_array.inspect
```

provide the output

```
["host1","host2"]
```

I was hoping to use one of those.
Unfortunately, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make that work.
I've tried each of the following:

```
<% p hosts %>
<% puts hosts.inspect %>
```

I found somewhere where they indicated I'd need to put "function_" in front of function calls...that doesn't seem to work. I've settled on an iterative model:

```
[<% hosts.each do |host| -%>"<%=host%>",<% end -%>]
```

this works, giving me

```
["host1","host2",]
```

but the trailing comma feels sloppy.  the whole thing feels sloppy.  Does anyone have a better way? Or is what I've done the best option?

Answer (score 5):

I've solved (Puppet v3.0.1) this way:

```
{
    "your_key1": {
        "your_key2": [<% puppet_var.join('", "').each do |val| %>"<%= val %>"<% end -%>]
    }
}
```

If $puppet_var is an array like [ "a", "b" ] output should look something like:

```
{
    "your_key1": {
        "your_key2": ["a", "b"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby allows the use of the %w shorcut between brackets to initialize arrays. This will do:

```
hosts = %w{<%= hosts.join(' ') %>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_json`;

```
hosts.to_json
=> "[\"host1\",\"host2\"]"
```

Comment: I'll still need to do some post-processing of that to strip out the escape characters and extra quotes, won't I?

Comment: Nah they're escaped because they're inside double quotes.  That's what it would look like in console.  When you output it in the erb it'll be fine.

Comment: ah.  apparently puppet doesn't understand that.

    Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template tools/link_config.erb:#012  Filepath: /etc/puppet/environments/ultradns_development/modules/tools/templates/link_config.erb#012  Line: 2#012  Detail: undefined method `to_json' for ["puppetmaster-useast1b01-01.dev.ultradns.net"]:Array#012 at /etc/puppet/environments/ultradns_development/modules/tools/manifests/link_scripts.pp:31 on node job-useast1b01-01.dev.ultradns.net

Comment: sorry, yeah.  I didn't read your question carefully enough and made the assumption that it was for rails.  `to_s` seems like it should work in this case.  Actually, your initial `HOSTS=<%= hosts %>` seems like it should work.  You're sure that it doesn't?

Comment: I get the output 

hosts="host1 host2"

when I do that.  unless I'm much mistaken (and I may be - I'm very new to ruby...) that will give me a string containing "host1 host2" instead of an array containing "host1" and "host2" - correct?
I could deal with that if I could convert that into an array, but at that point I might as well use the hosts.each syntax I've got and just live with the trailing comma.